# Which is the answer for Sin(2πx0,6248)

Tags: excel, pi, trigonometry

In an exercise, the problem: Sin(2πx0,6248) gave me two different answers, one at the calculator (0,06846) and another on the excel, where I used =SEN(2*3,14159265359*A2) 
(A2 = 0,6248). For this one the answer was -0,7062.

Why did I get those two different answers? And which one is the right answer?

Comment: I think you are mixing DEGREES and RADIANS

Comment: but you are in the worng place

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a bit unclear with no expected answer provided.

Excel's [SIN function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/SIN-function-cf0e3432-8b9e-483c-bc55-a76651c95602) expects *'the angle in radians for which you want the sine'* (see [RADIANS function](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/RADIANS-function-ac409508-3d48-45f5-ac02-1497c92de5bf)). If you are looking for the sine of 0.6248° then the correct formula is,

```
=sin(radians(0,6248))
```

Example:

```
=sin(radians(30))    ◄ returns 0.5
```

A full list of the available trigonometric function is available at: [Math and trigonometry functions (reference)](https://support.office.com/en-in/article/math-and-trigonometry-functions-reference-ee158fd6-33be-42c9-9ae5-d635c3ae8c16).